# Seeking online resources for creating shp files performing basic GI functionality

Tags: shapefile, polygon-creation, geoprocessing-service, service-recommendations

I am looking to build polygons, based on files containing a grid of points.  The representation of the polygon would be an aggregation of the points. As the end wares are Esri, I was wondering if there were online resources for performing this type of object creation; creating shape files based on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a web service, but you could use the Point to Polygon tool from ET Geowizard (free).